# What is the name of the following bad "average"?

Tags: terminology

Is there a standard name for the "average" of the fractions $a/b$ and $c/d$ as
$$
\frac{a+c}{b+d} \, \large ?
$$
I understand that such an average is not unique in the sense that although $(2a)/(2b) = a/b$, this type of "average" of $2a/(2b)$ and $c/d$ is not the same as the above (in general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [mediant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mediant.html). It appears in statistics, e.g., in [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox).

Answer (score 1):

The place this happens naturally is in simple continued fractions. Convergents $p/q$ always have $\gcd(p,q) = 1.$ Given two consecutive convergents, your $a/b$ followed by $c/d,$ the result of the next "digit" being equal to $1$ is precisely that the next convergent is the mediant. If the next "digit" is some $k,$ the new convergent is
$$ \frac{a + kc}{b + kd} $$
which is also between  the first two.

The next set of relationships is that $ad-bc = \pm 1$ for an actual continued fraction. If that holds, then $c(b+kd)-d(a+kc) = \mp 1$
The matrix version is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
a & c \\
b & d
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
1 & k
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
c & a+kc \\
d & b+kd
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Whatever the determinant of the first matrix, it is negated in the product because the determinant of the second matrix is $-1$